# How to handle populating dropdown with Hibernate and JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp, jpa

Hey guys I am learning Hibernate & JPA with a simple project which allows the user to *Edit* a Student Info fields from a MySQL DB. There are two tables - one for the **Student** & one for his/hers **Favorite Movie**. The **Student** can choose only one movie from a dropdown, however I can't think of how to populate the dropdown with the data(*the name of the movie*) from **Favorite Movie** table

**Student.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s")})
public class Student implements Serializable {    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_student")
    private Integer idStudent;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_movie", referencedColumnName = "id_movie")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private FavoriteMovie favoriteMovie;
    
    /* Getters/Setters */
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (idStudent != null ? idStudent.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (!(object instanceof Student)) {
            return false;
        }
        Student other = (Student) object;
        if ((this.idStudent == null && other.idStudent != null) || (this.idStudent != null && !this.idStudent.equals(other.idStudent))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" + "idStudent=" + idStudent + 
                ", name=" + name + 
                ", favoriteMovie=" + favoriteMovie + '}';
    }
}
```

**FavoriteMovie.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "favorite_movie")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "FavoriteMovie.findAll", query = "SELECT m FROM FavoriteMovie m")})
public class FavoriteMovie implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_movie")
    private Integer idFavoriteMovie;

    @Column(name = "movie_name")
    private String favoriteMovieName;

    @Column(name = "movie_year")
    private int favoriteMovieYear;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "favoriteMovie")
    private List<Student> studentList;
    
    public FavoriteMovie() {
    }    
    
    public FavoriteMovie(Integer idFavoriteMovie) {
        this.idFavoriteMovie = idFavoriteMovie;
    }

    public FavoriteMovie(Integer idFavoriteMovie, String favoriteMovieName) {
        this.idFavoriteMovie = idFavoriteMovie;
        this.favoriteMovieName = favoriteMovieName;
    }   
    /* Getters/Setters */
}
```

**EditServlet.java**

```
@WebServlet("/EditServlet")
public class EditServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        String idStudent = request.getParameter("idStudent");

        StudentService studentService = new StudentService();

        Student student = studentService.findStudent(Integer.parseInt(idStudent));
        
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("student", student);
        
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/editStudent.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        
        String action = request.getParameter("modify");
        if ("modify".equals(action)) {
        
            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            Student student = (Student) session.getAttribute("student");            
            
            student.setName(name);
            
            String favoriteMovieName = request.getParameter("favoriteMovieName");

            student.getFavoriteMovie().setFavoriteMovieName(favoriteMovieName);     
            
            
            StudentService studentService = new StudentService();
            studentService.saveStudent(student);
            
            session.removeAttribute("student");

        }
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

**editStudent.jsp**

```
<body>
        Modify Student
        <br/>
        <form name ="form1" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/EditServlet" method="post">
            Id Student: <input type="text" name="idStudent" value="${student.idStudent}" readonly="readonly"><br/>
            Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="${student.name}"><br/>

            Favorite Movie: <select name="selectedFavoriteMovie" id="selectedFavoriteMovie"> 
                <c:forEach var="favoriteMovie" items="" >
                    <option value="">
                        
                    </option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select><br/><br/>
            
            <input type="submit" name="edit" value="edit">
            
        </form>
    </body>
```

The dropdown has to be populated with all the *movies names* from the **FavoriteMovies** table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it could quite fit for your current solutions without so much modifications :)
I suppose - since you have a StudentService - you also have a FavoriteMovieService that could do:

```
List<FavoriteMovie> movies = new FavoriteMovieService().getAll();
```

If so - you could add an additional attribute for servlet on GET request as follows:

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    String idStudent = request.getParameter("idStudent");

    StudentService studentService = new StudentService();

    Student student = studentService.findStudent(Integer.parseInt(idStudent));

    List<FavoriteMovie> movies = new FavoriteMovieService().getAll();
    
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("student", student);
    session.setAttribute("movies", movies);
    
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/editStudent.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

After that you would be able to iterate through that list in the JSP:

```
<c:forEach items="${movies}" var="movie">
  <option value="${movie.getFavoriteMovieName()}">${movie.getFavoriteMovieName()}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

That should work for you :)

**UPD:**

1. How to show the selected movie in the dropdown:

```java
    <c:forEach items="${movies}" var="movie">
      <option value="${movie}" selected="${movie.getFavoriteMovieName() == student.getFavouriteMovie().getFavouriteMovieName()}">${movie.getFavoriteMovieName()}</option>
    </c:forEach>
```

2. How to update the movie:

```java
 @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        
        String action = request.getParameter("modify");
        if ("modify".equals(action)) {
        
            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            Student student = (Student) session.getAttribute("student");            
            
            student.setName(name);
            
            FavoriteMovie favoriteMovie = request.getParameter("favoriteMovieName");

            student.setFavoriteMovie(favoriteMovie);     
            
            StudentService studentService = new StudentService();
            studentService.saveStudent(student);
            
            session.removeAttribute("student");

        }
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: hey this works very nice with listing all of the movies available. However there are 2 problems I can't solve. When trying to change the favorite movie of a student, the form doesn't submit the new favorite movie. And when the student has a favorite movie it is not selected in the dropdown. Can you give me a push one more time :)

Comment: Sure! I'll update the question for you soon)

Comment: When trying to change the movie title, it's changing the value in the FavoriteMovie table which is unwanted behaviour, because I just the Student to be switching between movies and not modify the Favorite Movie table.

Comment: Hi! Please, stick to:
`<c:forEach items="${movies}" var="movie">
      <option value="${movie}" selected="${movie.getFavoriteMovieName() == student.getFavouriteMovie().getFavouriteMovieName()}">${movie.getFavoriteMovieName()}</option>
    </c:forEach>`


Where use pass the whole FavoriteMovie class as value, but not only the movie name. And save it as follows:
`FavoriteMovie favoriteMovie = request.getParameter("favoriteMovieName");
student.setFavoriteMovie(favoriteMovie);`


That will update the reference to FavoriteMovie for the Student record and will not re-write the movie
`

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
<select name="selectedFavoriteMovie" id="selectedFavoriteMovie">
```

so you also should could do:

```
request.getParameter("selectedFavoriteMovie");
```

Also instead of

```
<option value="${movie.getFavoriteMovieName()}">${movie.getFavoriteMovieName()}</option>
```

you could do:

```
<option value="${movie}">${movie.getFavoriteMovieName()}</option>
```

In this case, variable selectedFavoriteMovie will be type FavoriteMovie instead of String, and you will be able to do `student.setFavoriteMovie(selectedFavoriteMovie);`

To select actual selectedFavoriteMovie you need to add `selected` to `option` . It can be done by a few way, e.g

```
<option value="${movie}" ${movie.getId() == student.getFavoriteMovie().getId() ? "selected" : ""}>${movie.getFavoriteMovieName()}</option>
```